# Xcode 11.4 / iOS13.3.1 Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, xcode, build-time

```
Details

Unable to install "wtsp_ios"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011c05981a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011c09af70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101e6e155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011c09aca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011bf11e91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101fa17f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101fa3436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e99d6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e99e658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e9a3c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e9a45d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e9adc09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ebf8a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ebf7b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4.1 (16137)
```

Anyone knows what trigger this? I added some frameworks and this happens.
Simulator also end with similar information.
I've tried clea build folder, system reboot, Xcode reboot, delete DerivedData folder, still not working, please help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it's because a framework that I linked should not be embled and signed, shut the option to "Do not emble" solved this.

Comment: “Emble”? Do you mean “embed”?

Comment: Thanks! that was the solution for me too. I had been messing around with the Embed options. Googled for more than 3 hours and even wrote Apple Developer Support. This answer was very useful. I changed some of my 3rd party frameworks to "Do Not Embed" and that solved it.