# Swift & Xcode : Unable to install "MyApp"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I was trying to run my application to my actual device. But I couldn't install it. I have no idea why. Could anyone give me a pointer on this issue? Thank you.

```
Unable to install "MyApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013029bc8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001302da241 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f34264b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001302d9f82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000013014aa10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f47117e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f472da0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202765dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff202777c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2027d5fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2027e0cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20287c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2041f499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2041e467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.2.3 (Build 20D91)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
Timestamp: 2021-05-13T15:49:43+09:00
```

Comment: Do you have a paid developer membership?

Comment: Yes and it will be expired within 29 days. Would it affect my project or sth?

Comment: Well you can’t run on a device if the paid membership expires. But you say it hasn’t.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that my old projects work just fine but I can't create a new one.

Comment: See if you have selected the right team in Build Settings.

Comment: Could it be because of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452540/2227743)?

Comment: Can you build a brand new project to your device?

Comment: Could it be that the iOS version of your device is either more recent or much older than your Xcode version? Neither your macOS version nor your Xcode version are latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and continue to have it still.

The device I was using to test applications is the initial iPhone X distribution.
I could install the application just fine on other devices.

`"Could not inspect the application package"` means you were probably stuck on the pkgConfig part of the install process, no doubt on your second run (it usually gets stuck before then on the first try).

**"Clean Build Folder"** is your first bet for what could fix the issue. It doesn't fully for me.

---

However I found a way to install applications on my phone, but it is very hacky.

**The trick is to **"Clean Build Folder"**, disconnect your device when it's in the build stage, and reconnect it before the build stage is over.
You will then have to re-install the application on the device after you get stuck the first time.**

Do not uninstall the application on your device (not that you can even if you wanted, if it is the same issue as mine).
I will warn that Xcode tends to crash when you disconnect your device mid-install like so.

Best of luck to you, cause you're gonna need it.

Answer (score 1):

if you have "Sign In with Your Apple ID" instead of "Apple Developer Program", you have only run one project on your real device. Also you have only one device register your membership during the free memberships.

[compare memberships details](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the USB port where the cable is connected